# Is it possible to import (paste) images into draw.io?

Tags: images, app.diagrams.net

While I love the rich image set readily available to me, I'd like to include custom images (my drawings, photos...) in draw.io documents. Is it possible?

I've tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> with a clipboard image but with no success.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The marked answer is old and is no longer correct.
Click *Arrange → Insert → Insert Image*.

FYI make sure to:

- click the checkbox to "remember my decision"
- click the button "actual size" (otherwise the program will resize your image to something that is very low resolution and then your image will be very blurry)

Comment: this answer is technically correct, I'd prefer the drag and drop method

Comment: This answer is correct for the current version, and once you go through the steps of this method it allows for drag and drop, as well as a URL.

Comment: directly importing from local file can resize your image. You need to do the trick: keep the draw.io's page active, drag your image, before the mouse reach the page's region, remember to press and keep Ctrl button, then drop it in the page.

Comment: Em português esse mesmo comando encontra-se no menu "EXTRAS"

Comment: Is this answer still accurate in 2021 ? In particular, now that copying images stored in the clipboard is easy, is there now a way in aggie.io to paste images from the clipboard somehow ?

Comment: as of this comment datetime, the solution still works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to go logged into a Google Account to import images. When you are, click the image icon (4th from right on toolbar) and the Google Image Picker appears. Select from the options on the left to either DnD an image into the picker or pick an image from the local filesystem.

Comment: Ah, the Image icon. Now I feel really embarrassed (is long day at work a valid excuse? :-) ). Thank you for your help (unfortunately I cannot upvote you as I don't have enough rep right now).

Comment: removed my answer friend

Comment: I can't seem to find the option to load from "local filesystem".  Having only just started using draw.io, I'm reluctant to hook it straight up to my Google Drive.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael12345 Just drag and drop the images from your file explorer to the diagram.

Comment: Oh wow @David, that's awesome - it works.  I'm starting to really really like this software.

Answer (score 3):

You can now simply drag-and-drop an image file onto the canvas to insert an image.

**Precautionary note:** If you are worried your browser will consider the dropped image as a link and set your url to the path of the image, potentially making you lose progress, then you can simply open a new draw.io tab, drag and drop the image on there, `ctrl+c` it, go back to your first draw.io tab, `ctrl+v`.

Comment: ctrl+c then ctrl+v on a new draw.io tab does not work. It remains a link. You have to save the image to local drive and then drag it back onto the draw.io diagram.

Comment: Hi Curtis! I just tested it, worked with me on Chrome ... here's exactly what I did: Opened two draw.io tabs, drag and drop an image onto the first one, it loaded, clicked the image, ctrl+c, moved to the next tab, ctrl+v

Comment: Right-click your image, choose "Edit Image". Does it start with "data:" or "http"? When I do your exact steps, my copied image remains a link (http).

Comment: Starts with 'data:', are you dragging an image from another tab? I was dragging images from my desktop ... but I just tried dragging an image from another tab (url ends with .jpg) and it copy pasted fine onto another draw.io tab too, it did start with 'https:' too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding graphical representation for [@Sridhar Jammalamadaka's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90497/201176) along with re-sizing tip

1. Click `Arrange → Insert → Image...`

[image]

---

2. Either put image URL or click `Open` to pick image from your local storage

[image]

---

3. Resize / move the image as per your liking

   - If the image is skewed to uneven proportions (happens quite often), then **uncheck `Constrain Proportions`** from the `Arrange` tab of right-side pane (that appears when inserted image is selected)
   - After that you'll be able to bring back the image to it's original proportions by manually moving the handles around the image
   - Once you've restored the image to desired proportion, you can **re-check `Constrain Proportions`** to keep that aspect ratio locked while you resize the image further

[image]

Comment: Also see [Reset draw.io image 'full size' setting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164407/201176)