# Reset draw.io image 'full size' setting

Tags: app.diagrams.net

- While [inserting image into `draw.io`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90497/201176), I selected `Remember this setting` checkbox
- Now how can I reset this setting (as it wouldn't prompt me again)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per the [drawio.freshdesk support page](https://drawio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000042480-add-images-to-your-diagram), this setting can be reset by

- Going into browser's debugger console
- And deleting the `database (default)` under `_Indexed DB` section
- Followed by doing a `Delete All` under `Local storage` section

[image]

---

Other useful links

- [Is it possible to import (paste) images into draw.io?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164316/201176)
- [How to change "Remember this setting" in Draw io Desktop](https://groups.google.com/g/drawio/c/8CjO64PDdXo)